# Positive, Uni-modal, Log-concave Combinatorics

Tags: inequalities, taylor-series

We define a sequence, $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$, to be a uni-modal sequence if for some $m$, $$a_0<a_1<\cdots<a_m,\ \ \ \ a_m>a_{m+1}>a_{m+2}>\cdots.$$

We define a sequence, $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$, to be log-concave if for all $k$, $$\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}>\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_k}.$$

For every positive, uni-modal, log-concave sequence, does there exist an $n$ so that, $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (a_{k+1}-a_k)(-1)^{n-k}\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (a_{k+1}+a_k)(-1)^{n-k}\right) <0?$$

Note, that if we define $$f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!}x^k,$$ then $$\left.\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x))\right)\right|_{x=0} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (a_{k+1}-a_k)(-1)^{n-k}\right)$$ and $$\left.\left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}e^{-x}(f'(x)+f(x))\right)\right|_{x=0} = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (a_{k+1}+a_k)(-1)^{n-k}\right)$$

Hence, our question pertains to the functions $e^{-x}(f'-f)$ and $e^{-x}(f'+f)$; can we prove that these functions must have at least one Taylor coefficient of opposite sign?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question?

Comment: You probably mean $a_m>a_{m+1}>\ldots$ in the definition of unimodal.

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson My motivation of this problem is related to functions in the Laguerre-Polya class (entire functions that can be uniformly approximated by real-rooted polynomials). Functions in this class with positive coefficients have log-concave coefficients that are either unimodal (eventually decreasing), decreasing, or increasing. In the increasing case, it is known that my question is false. What is not really understood is the decreasing case or uni-modal case. For a more analytic perspective, see http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/mathfiles/gausslucas.pdf